# Why does my slideshow have many excess blank pages on the epub reader?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, xhtml, epub

I am Developing an android epub 2 reader my reader running smooth except on slideshow it always have excess 5 pages.My slideshow has 15 images with 270px height, My first conclusion was all the image in my slideshow adds on the total length of my epub then it was divided in 728px(the width of my webview),that's why I formed a condition that will total all the height of the images then I subtract it to the total length of my epub and divided to 728px but answer is insufficient to display the exact pages. It only displayed 11 pages instead of 12pages..

here is my code in Javascript:

function calculateOffset(firstLoad){

```
var offset = 0;
var pos = $('#' + pageEndMarker).position();
var slideshowImageHeight = 0;
var listLength = 0;
var slideshowExist = false;

    if(document.getElementById("slideshow")){       
    slideshowExist = true;
    var images, list;
            var ImageHeight = 0;
            slideshowExist = true;

            //This code is for getting all the ul elements with "slideshow" id
            //and total all the length of all the li element; 
    images = document.getElementById("slideshow");
    list = images.getElementsByTagName('li');
            // the answer is 15 becaused it has 15 list of images
    listLength = list.length;

    //this code is to compute the total height of the images.
    //I did subtract 1 on the listLength,because i will subtract the listLength with the value of 14 elements on the total epub length. so that only one image size will add to the total epub length and that will serve as the height of the entire slideshow.
    for(var i = 0; i < listLength-1; i++) {
        imgHeight += $("li").height();                         
        slideshowImageHeight = imgHeight;//the answer is 11648              

    }           
}

    if(pos!=null){
    var excessWidth = pos.left % desiredWidth;
    if(excessWidth > desiredWidth / 2) {
        offset = (pos.left + desiredWidth) - excessWidth;       
    } else {
        offset = pos.left - excessWidth;

                    //this code is to subtract the total slideshowImageHeight
                    if(slideshowExist){
                        //the offset should have a value of 8008 instead of 7878 to be come 12pages in android code
                        offset = offset - slideshowImageHeight;//11648 - 3780 = 7868
                    }
             }
     }
```

here is my code on android:

```
  public void setOffset(int offsetWidth) {      
    if (VibeGlobalData.mVibeReaderActivity != null) {
        VibeGlobalData.mVibeReaderActivity.getWebView().setOffsetWidth(
                offsetWidth);           
        int width = getWidth();         
        if (width > 0) {    
                            //this code divides the total offset from javascript 
            int pageSize = offsetWidth / width; // 7868 / 728 = 10.8076                 
            VibeGlobalData.mVibeBook.setCurrentPageSize(pageSize);//this code has a class that will get the total pageSize = 10.8076 then rounded to 10 then adds 1 = 11 pages;
        }
        VibeGlobalData.mVibeReaderActivity.sendHandlerMsg(
                VibeReaderActivity.GUIHandler.MSG_OFFSET_CHANGED, null);
    }
}
```

here is the code for my epub 2:
but this is already resized to width = 462px & height = 270px:

```
  <!-- SLIDESHOW--> 
    <div class="slideshow-wrap">
      <ul class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide1.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide2.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide3.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide4.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide5.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide6.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide7.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide8.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide9.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide10.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide11.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide12.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide13.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide14.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
        <li ><img src="assets/images/she-epow1_p47_slide15.png" style="width: 700px;" /></li>
      </ul>
      <nav class="slideshow-controls"> <a class="play">&#187;</a> </nav>
    </div>
```

I observe other epub reader, Some reader only displayed list of images not slideshow, other reader also has the same problem as mind it has 5 excess pages and other doesn't displayed slideshow at all.. Is it possible for epub 2 to display a slideshow without any bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
style="width: 700px; max-width:100%"
```

to `<img>` element